# OpenCV 3.4.0 - zlibd1.dll was not found

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, visual-studio-2017

I have the following program, which is the same as [this tutorial page for OpenCV 3.4.0](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dd/d6e/tutorial_windows_visual_studio_opencv.html). I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community on a 64-bit laptop with Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit.

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2)
    {
     cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

    if( image.empty() ) // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); // Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image ); // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

With the includes and linker directories and libraries set up for this project, the solution builds just fine. But when I run the program, I get the following error:

**"The code execution cannot proceed because zlibd1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."**

From my initial research, it's not necessarily coming from Visual Studio 2017. When I try to create a new project, I do not have the option to select "Win32 Console Application." The project this source code sits in is of type Windows Console Application under Visual C++, supporting .NET Framework 4.5.

What am I missing here?

Based on the tutorial, I should be using only the libraries and the dynamic link libraries OpenCV 3.4.0 provides. I remember at one point using NuGET to try to install OpenCV 3.4.0 again, [as explained here](http://funvision.blogspot.com/2017/04/simple-install-opencv-visual-studio.html), when I was trying to solve the compiler error regarding fopen from a file within OpenCV 3.4.0 itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apparently it was a problem regarding my system path. It was not set right, Before, what I had was the path variable set to the following:

```
%OPENCV_DIR%\lib
%OPENCV_DIR%\bin
```

with $(OPENCV_DIR) being just the build directory of OpenCV 3.4.0.

But the directories there do not exist, and hence the libraries couldn't be found. So, I replaced them with this:

```
%OPENCV_DIR%\x64\vc15\bin
%OPENCV_DIR%\x64\vc15\lib
```

and the program now runs. What was I thinking back there?

Either way, important lesson to note: **When you are getting a popup message saying the program cannot be opened because a library is missing, and is part of OpenCV 3.4.0, *be sure that your system path* in the Windows 10 System Advanced Settings is an OpenCV directory that *exists*.**

Answer (score 1):

This package has a problem to run under debug and result in zlibd1.dll problem. Switch to release if you can or use different nuget package.

[image: **enter image description here**]

[image]